# OverflowException reading decimal value from db

Tags: .net, sql-server, decimal

I have a sql server column defined decimal(32,15).  When I try to read it using SqlDataReader.GetValue(), I find that the maximum db value that can be accommodated is 79,228,162,514,264.   A larger value throws an overflowexception.  This is surprising, since the .net decimal type is 128 bits and provides 28 to 29 digits of precision.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SqlDataReader.GetSqlDecimal()` instead of `SqlDataReader.GetValue()`.

Here is an example of the problem in detail:

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2010/08/31/when-does-sql-server-decimal-not-convert-to-net-decimal.aspx

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the link.  Looks like a .net defect.

Answer (score 1):

This also works: `SqlDataReader.GetProviderSpecificValue()`